Comonotone solution for Optimal Transport problems with supermodular surplus
In Alfred Galichon's book Optimal Transport Methods in Economics the foollowing result is stated for OT problems on the real line.
Theorem 4.3.(i) Assume that $\Phi$ is supermodular. Then the primal of the Monge-Kantorovich problem
$$
\sup_{\pi \in M(P, Q)} \mathbb{E}_\pi [\Phi(X, Y)]
$$
has a comonotone solution.
In the chapter, Galichon assumes that the surplus $\Phi$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$. Hence, I understand that, even if not stated, one should maintan this hypothesis also for the result above.
Now, my question is: do you know another reference for this result, possibly relaxing the $C^2$ assumption?

For the sake of clarity, please add the definitions of "supermodular" and "comonotone".

There is a proof right after the statement of the theorem. No differentiability assumption is needed.

@MichaelGreinecker thanks! I have seen the proof. But at some point he writes that the results hold by approximation in the case where the domain is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. I was afraid the assumption may come into play therein.

The approximation goes from compact rectangles to the plane. Differentiability makes no difference there.
